# Extracting Text Within Tags Inside HTML Comments with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, text-extraction

I want to extract the text within list element inside a comment without the list tags.But I can't do it with the code below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment


html = """
<html>
<body>
<!--
  <ul>
     <li>10</li>
     <li>20</li>
     <li>30</li>
     </ul>
 -->

</body>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for numbers in soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment)):
    print(numbers.extract())
```

Result is:

```
<ul>
<li>10</li>
<li>20</li>
<li>30</li>
</ul>
```

Desired result :

```
10
20
30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below approach. It will fetch you the result you wish to get.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

html = """
<html>
<body>
<!--
  <ul>
     <li>10</li>
     <li>20</li>
     <li>30</li>
     </ul>
 -->

</body>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.find_all(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment)):
    data = BeautifulSoup(item,"html.parser")
    for number in data.find_all("li"):
        print(number.text)
```

Output:

```
10
20
30
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for all "li" and print just the text.

```
for tag in soup.find_all("li"):
        print(tag.text))
```

Comment: It doesn't work.List items are in between comment tags <!--...-->. I can extract from comments but can't get the text inside the list items.